# react-testing-library expect onclick to throw new error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

How do I test throw error onClick for react-testing-library

index.js

```
function HomePage() {
    return (
        <Flex>
            <p>Hello World</p>

            <button
                type="button"
                data-testid="error-btn"
                onClick={() => {
                    throw new Error('Frontend Error');
                }}
            >
                Throw error
            </button>
        </Flex>
    );
}

export default HomePage;
```

index.test.js

```
    it('should throw error when click button', () => {
        const {getByTestId} = render(<Home />);
        const errorBtn = getByTestId( 'error-btn')
       expect(fireEvent.click(errorBtn)).toThrowError('Frontend Error')
    })
```

I expect it the catch the error

Comment: This demo doesn't make sense, you should use the JS `try...catch...` statement if an error may be thrown from the event handler. See https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#how-about-event-handlers

Comment: @LinDu Yes, But I using this error to test sentry implementation. so i need something to trigger and error on frontend